# Partial differential equation 5

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Which change of variable should I do to solve this PDE?

$u_{xy}(x, y) + au_x(x, y) + bu_y(x, y) + abu(x, y) = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(u_x+bu)_y+a(u_x+bu)=0$$
Let $v=u_x+bu$,then solve two ODEs